# Formating a CSS table and form

Tags: html, css

When trying to formatting a CSS table eg: display: table; - is there any way to have the table to fill the surrounding form.

```css
 label {
   font: 1em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   /* width: 20em; */
 }

 label::after {
   content: " :";
 }

 input[type=text] {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   /* width: 20em; */
   /* width: 100%;*/
 }

 input[type=submit] {
   font: 1.1em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   height: 30px;
   width: 100px;
   margin-top: 5px;
 }

 form {
   border: 2px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
 }

 #my-table {
   display: table;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 2px solid red;
 }

 #my-table-row {
   display: table-row;
 }

 #my-table-cell-caption {
   display: table-caption;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   font: 1.4em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
 }

 #my-table-cell-input {
   display: table-cell;
   /* border: 1px solid blue; */
   padding: 2px;
   background-color: light-grey;
 }

 #my-table-cell-label {
   display: table-cell;
   color: black;
   /* border: 1px solid blue; */
   padding: 5px;
   /* width: 100px; */
   text-align: right;
 }

 #gh-form-submit-button {
   display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Form demo</h1>

<form>

  <div id='my-table'>

    <div id='my-table-cell-caption'>
      Person edit
    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>First name</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Last name</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>
      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div id='gh-form-submit-button'>
    <input type='submit' value='SAVE'>
  </div>

  <div id='gh-form-submit-button'>
    <input type='submit' value='DELETE'>
  </div>


</form>


<hr>

<address><a href="mailto:gorhas@raditex.nu">gorhas</a></address>
```

[The current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMiUu.png)

I want the table content to fill the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure did I understand you question correctly, but did you try to add these two lines to your #my-table?

```
#my-table {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `width: 100%` to your div ? also add `box-sizing:border-box` so the padding is included in the width.

Also, you have some problems in your HTML.

- Duplicate `id`'s are not allowed. For eg you are using
  `my-table-cell-label, gh-form-submit-button` and so on,  more than
  once. Please use unique id-s or `class` instead.
- Closing tags for `input` are not needed. `input` element doesn't accept
  any content ( just like `img` for eg ) so it is a self closing
  element : `<input />`

```css
 label {
   font: 1em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   /* width: 20em; */
 }

 label::after {
   content: " :";
 }

 input[type=text] {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   /* width: 20em; */
   /* width: 100%;*/
 }

 input[type=submit] {
   font: 1.1em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   height: 30px;
   width: 100px;
   margin-top: 5px;
 }

 form {
   border: 2px solid green;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
 }

 #my-table {
   display: table;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 2px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
 }

 #my-table-row {
   display: table-row;
 }

 #my-table-cell-caption {
   display: table-caption;
   background: #e9ecdf;
   font: 1.4em "typewriter", sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
 }

 #my-table-cell-input {
   display: table-cell;
   /* border: 1px solid blue; */
   padding: 2px;
   background-color: light-grey;
 }

 #my-table-cell-label {
   display: table-cell;
   color: black;
   /* border: 1px solid blue; */
   padding: 5px;
   /* width: 100px; */
   text-align: right;
 }

 #gh-form-submit-button {
   display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Form demo</h1>

<form>

  <div id='my-table'>

    <div id='my-table-cell-caption'>
      Person edit
    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>First name</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Last name</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>
      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id='my-table-row'>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-label'>
        <label>Field</label>
      </div>

      <div id='my-table-cell-input'>
        <input type="text" name="fname"></input>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div id='gh-form-submit-button'>
    <input type='submit' value='SAVE'>
  </div>

  <div id='gh-form-submit-button'>
    <input type='submit' value='DELETE'>
  </div>


</form>


<hr>

<address><a href="mailto:gorhas@raditex.nu">gorhas</a></address>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are setting the width to 100%, you need to override the max-width property.

```
max-width: 100% !important;
```